# allure-pytest: how to insert entries to the allure report for tests that don't exist

Tags: pytest, allure

I'm using allure-pytest. I'm using stories/markers to represent Test Plan requirements. I add a list of markers to pytest.ini file. In conftest.py I generate a set of markers that haven't been used. I'd like to add each missing marker as a skipped test to my allure report. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried creating tests in conftest.py

```
import pytest
import allure

import allure_commons
from allure_commons.model2 import TestResult, Status, Label, Parameter
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType
from allure_commons.reporter import AllureReporter
from allure_commons.utils import uuid4

def pytest_collection_finish(session):
    # get all the available markers defined in pytest.ini
    marker_dict = session.config.getini('markers')
    markers = set(marker_dict)

    # get all the markers used in the collected tests
    used_markers = set()
    for item in session.items:
        used_markers.update(set([m.name for m in item.iter_markers()]))

    # find the markers defined in pytest.ini but not used in any of the tests
    unused_markers = markers - used_markers

    item = session.items[0]

    # add skipped tests for the unused markers
    if unused_markers and item:
        print(item.parent)
        for marker in unused_markers:
            print("adding skipped test: ", marker)
            args = marker.split(":")
            name = args[0]
            add_external_test_result(name, "skipped")

            session.items.append(create_skipped_test(name, marker)) # generates an error for missing config

            #skipped_test = pytest.Function(name=f"test_missing_{name}", parent=None, config=item.config) # generates an error for deprecated method
            #skipped_test = item.from_parent(parent=item.parent, name=f"test_missing_{name}")
            #skipped_test.add_marker(pytest.mark.skip(reason=f"No test created for marker({marker})"))
            #session.items.append(skipped_test) # generates an error for the method not existing in the parent

def create_skipped_test(name, marker):
    # create a dummy test function with a skipped marker
    @pytest.mark.skip(reason=f"unmarked marker: {name}")
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures() # add any necessary fixtures
    def test_dummy():
        pass

    # add the marker to the test function
    test_dummy = pytest.mark.parametrize(name, [marker])(test_dummy)

    return test_dummy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was pretty tricky, but I think I have achieved desired behavior using `pytest_generate_tests` hook and `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook wrapper.

First of all, you need to add `test_dummy` somewhere in your `tests` directory like this:

**test_dummy.py**

```
def test_dummy():
    pass
```

Then in **conftest.py** you should define following hook functions:

```
import pytest
from _pytest.mark import Mark


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    # get all test_dummy instances (with each mark parameter)
    skip_tests = [item for item in items if item.originalname == "test_dummy"]
    # remove all test_dummy from items to prevent it's execution without skip mark
    items[:] = [item for item in items if item.originalname != "test_dummy"]
    # let all other pytest_collection_modifyitems filter items
    yield
    # get set of all used markers
    used_markers = set()
    for item in items:
        used_markers.update(set([m.name for m in item.iter_markers()]))

    for item in skip_tests:
        # get mark name from parameter name of test_dummy instance
        mark = item.name.rsplit("[")[-1][:-1]
        # if mark name is not in used markers set:
        if mark not in used_markers:
            # add test_dummy with this mark and skip mark to items list
            item.own_markers = [Mark(mark, (), {}), Mark("skip", (), {"reason": f"skip mark: `{mark}`"})]
            items.append(item)


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    """Generate parametrization for test_dummy instance using only custom markers from `pytest.ini`."""
    if metafunc.definition.name == "test_dummy":
        # get list of CUSTOM markers from pytest.ini (without pytest plugins builtins markers!)
        markers = set(mark.split(":", maxsplit=1)[0] for mark in metafunc.config._getini('markers'))
        # add mark parameter to function arguments
        if "mark" not in metafunc.fixturenames:
            metafunc.fixturenames.append("mark")
        metafunc.parametrize("mark", [pytest.param(mark) for mark in markers])
```

I have added some comments to code, so you can track it's logic.

Basically, it creates parametrize for `test_dummy` using every custom marker (defined in **pytest.ini**). Then it stores all of `test_dummy` instances in separate list and removes them from `items`.

After all filtering was done by other plugins (including pytest markers filtering) it gets list of used markers. For each `test_dummy` instance that has parameter which is not in used list we add `skip` mark and parameter name mark and add it to final `items` list.

**Example:**

I have following markers in pytest.ini: `smoke`, `regression`, `unit`.

I have one test for each marker. I run `pytest -m smoke --alluredir results`.

Here is the result in Allure.
[image: Allure example]

Let me know what you think. Is it what you tried to achieve?

**UPD**

Also you can add `@allure.title` for `test_dummy` to make it look better in report.

```
import allure


@allure.title("Skipped mark")
def test_dummy():
    pass
```

[image: allure.title]

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it generates everything I needed. Well done.